# Custom keymap not loading, I isolated Vaughan Ling's HEAVYPOLY setup's shortcut and put it in the 4.1\scripts\startup folder

Tags: scripting

What could be the reason for causing the keymap not to load? I already enabled the checkbox to run scripts automatically.

````py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Heavypoly Hotkeys",
    "description": "Hotkeys",
    "author": "Vaughan Ling",
    "version": (0, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Hotkeys"
    }

import bpy
import os

def kmi_props_setattr(kmi_props, attr, value):
    try:
        setattr(kmi_props, attr, value)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Warning: property '%s' not found in keymap item '%s'" %
              (attr, kmi_props.__class__.__name__))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Warning: %r" % e)

def Keymap_Heavypoly():

# Map DOPESHEET_EDITOR
    km = kc.keymaps.new('Dopesheet Editor', space_type='DOPESHEET_EDITOR', region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new('transform.transform', 'SPACE', 'PRESS')
    kmi_props_setattr(kmi.properties, 'mode', 'TIME_TRANSLATE')


def register():
    Keymap_Heavypoly()

def unregister():
    Keymap_Heavypoly()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````